# Meteor.js Template does not update after variable assignment

Tags: javascript, html, templates, dom, meteor

I'm building a free TV-tracking app with Meteor, and along the way I seem to have hit a wall. A part of my template contains this:

```
<template name="results">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="span6 offset6">
        <h4>Search Results</h4>
          <ul>
            {{#each series}}
            <li><a href="http://thetvdb.com/?tab=episode&seriesid{{tvdbseriesid}}&lid={{tvdblid}}">{{seriesname}}</li>
            {{/each}}
          </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Then, within my client js code, I do this:

```
Template.search.events({
  'click #search' : function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();

    var query = $('#query').val();
    if (query) {
      Meteor.call('queryshow', query, function(error, result) {
        Template.results.series = result;
        console.log(Template.results());
      });
    }
  }
});
```

The "queryshow" server method is just a Collection query method that returns an object containing the data that my template needs.

The problem is this however: the change isn't reflected in the browser window. I can't seem to figure out why, because the console.log(Template.results()) call shown below returns the correct html that I am expecting.

How do I fix this? I tried looking around Meteor's docs and I can't seem to find a function that forcibly re-renders a Template. Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: The whole code is available here by the way: [link](https://github.com/KixPanganiban/flickowl)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Template.results.series` should be a function that returns the series, rather than set directly to the series you want to use.  That way, when Meteor runs the function to get the series, it can register what the function depends on, and then re-run the function whenever any of the dependencies change.

The easiest way to register a dependency for your information is to use the `Session` object.  So your code would look something like:

```
Template.results.series = function () { return Session.get('resultsSeries'); }

Meteor.call('queryshow', query, function (err, res) {
  // handle the error if it's there
  // ...
  // Then set the session variable, which will re-run anything that depends on it.
  Session.set('resultsSeries', res)
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks so much! A follow up question here, how do I achieve the same thing if I use a different variable rather than the session one? Such that when it changes, it will re-run any function that attaches to it. Thanks!